# Dynamic open_basedir with mod_vhost_alias

Tags: php, apache, open-basedir, mod-vhost-alias

I'm using mod_vhost_alias and want to set dynamically open_basedir for each user. Something like

php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/vhosts/%1

But it doesn't work. Because I have a lot of virtual hosts (4000-5000) mod_macro does not suit me.

I'm trying to apply this patch
http://wiki.preshweb.co.uk/doku.php?id=apache:securemassvhosting

But with no success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [auto_prepend](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) option in php.ini to supply script that will be executed first.
There you can setup open_basedir via ini_set() function based on contents of $_SERVER array.

Comment: Yeah, something like this could do it: `ini_set('open_basedir', "/var/www/hosts/$hostname/:/tmp/");`

Comment: A useful note: php will not let any following `ini_set` to loosen the restriction.
So if you set it to `/var/www/html` in a prepend file, a following `ini_set('open_basedir', "/");` will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

May be somebody would be interested. I have successfully changed the patch (http://www.phpbuilder.com/lists/php-developer-list/2000101/0994.php)

```
*** main/fopen_wrappers.c       2010-04-22 01:22:31.000000000 +0300
--- main/fopen_wrappers.c       2012-03-14 17:22:49.130299133 +0200
***************
*** 145,156 ****
--- 145,168 ----
        char resolved_name[MAXPATHLEN];
        char resolved_basedir[MAXPATHLEN];
        char local_open_basedir[MAXPATHLEN];
+       char *local_open_basedir_sub; /* Substring pointer for strstr */
        char path_tmp[MAXPATHLEN];
        char *path_file;
        int resolved_basedir_len;
        int resolved_name_len;
        int path_len;
        int nesting_level = 0;
+
+       /* Special case for VIRTUAL_DOCUMENT_ROOT in the open_basedir value, which gets changed to the document root */
+       if ((strncmp(basedir, "VIRTUAL_DOCUMENT_ROOT", strlen("VIRTUAL_DOCUMENT_ROOT")) == 0) && SG(request_info).path_translated && *SG(request_info).path_translated )
+       {
+           strlcpy(local_open_basedir, SG(request_info).path_translated, sizeof(local_open_basedir));
+
+           local_open_basedir_sub=strstr(local_open_basedir,SG(request_info).request_uri);
+           /* Now insert null to break apart the string */
+           if (local_open_basedir_sub) *local_open_basedir_sub = '\0';
+
+       } else

        /* Special case basedir==".": Use script-directory */
        if (strcmp(basedir, ".") || !VCWD_GETCWD(local_open_basedir, MAXPATHLEN)) {
```

It was tested with php-5.3.10 and it's worked great.